# How to run own project on bitnami ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache2, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I have my own old django project which has not been created through django 1.4.1. I want to host it on ec2 bitnami so that inspite of running default htdocs folder my desired folder must be displayed. I have done this before but this time with new machine its not running. I have been go through this link

http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/djangostack/topics/getting-started

and was already all that. My changes what i have are..

In httpd.conf

**In myproject_cofig.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /fortis_django "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/conf/fortis_django_wsgi.wsgi"\


<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/conf'>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**In myproject_wsgi.wsgi**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/')
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/projects/')
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/projects/fortis_django')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'fortis_django.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And location of project is checked and its correct..

**In httpd.conf** i changed..

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects" 

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/conf/fortis_django_config.conf"
```

And redirected also..

> RedirectMatch /fortis /fortis_django/login

So, whenever i go to myurl/fortis it come myurl/fortis_django/login with error too many loops. I am stucked from days please help to run my own project from my location. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/fortis$ /fortis_django/login
```

Your existing pattern will not match what you are redirecting to.

Comment: ERROR: The requested URL /fortis_django/login was not found on this server. But i have added all the conf ans wsgi also checked the instruction fortis_django.settings is there. What i have to do next?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to use '/fortis/login', because your above Apache configuration is not going to map the URL '/fortis_django/login' to anything. Go read the Apache documentation about what RedirectMatch does and what the two arguments need to be.

Comment: i have also tried with /fortis_django in apache conf but result is still same. I dont know why wsgi file not working because if it works then /login would work because of URL.py know that where to navigate this page. It means fortis_django.settings not been imported and this instruction is in wsgi file. Please help i am still working on it.

Comment: Now that you have edited your configuration and changed the mount point for WSGIScriptAlias, did you add the ^$ around the pattern in the first argument of the RedirectMatch. If you do not have that, it will still match /fortis_django after the redirect and so loop. You need to have ^$ so it matches only on /fortis and not when it is a prefix to a longer URL.

Comment: I have already tried as u said RedirectMatch ^/fortis$ /fortis_django/login now it is giving The requested URL /fortis_django/login was not found on this server. I checked twice there is associated URL defined in URL.PY. I already done all settings. Why i am still encountering this error?

Comment: Thanks now finally its running but with some error again that is 




Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.


And i checked the apache error_log file, it is showing

File does not exist: {my directory}/favicon.ico

Comment: Set DEBUG to True temporarily in Django settings and may show error error in browser. One posibility for a 500 like you see is that you don't have 404/500 pages defined for Django. Also make sure you aren't setting ErrorDocument directives for Apache and trying to have Django serve up error pages. If it is and the URLs specified by ErrorDocument don't exist, Django will return 404 causing Apache to return an obsucre 500 error with no details.

Comment: Now everything is running but while working on web i am encountering 

(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

what does it mean? and how can i fix this problem. Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Either MySQL isn't running, or your Apache user doesn't have permissions to access that socket if it does exist.